# Antd: Tooltip on table row

Tags: javascript, antd

I've created a table in antd, but i need that when the mouse is over the row a tooltip should show.

I'm doing this in the columns definition (rendering a tooltip for each cell), but in this way the tooltip hides between cells.

Example:

```
   {
            title: 'Fecha de Pedido',
            dataIndex: 'fecha_pedido',
            rowKey: 'fecha_pedido',
            key: 'fecha_pedido',
            sorter: (a, b) => moment(a.fecha_pedido).unix() - moment(b.fecha_pedido).unix(),
            render:(text, record)=>(
               
                <Tooltip title="Click para ver el detalle del pedido">
                <span>{moment(record.fecha_pedido).format('DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm a')}</span>
              </Tooltip> 
             
            ),
        },
```

Is there a way to show the tooltip in the entire row (instead of each cell)?

Thanks in advance, if you need any extra code snippet just please let me know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should custom table row component by `components.body.row` of `Table`'s props.

Example in CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/jibenyongfa-antd4150-forked-3djn4?file=/index.js:1742-1752